# Running a .net console app with wine in docker

Tags: docker, wine, container

I'm trying to run a simple hello world .NET 6 console app via wine in Docker

```
docker run -v c:\temp:/var/temp:Z --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash masonr/wineconsole
```

In the container I try to run the console app;

```
wineconsole /var/temp/test_wine/TestWine.exe
```

But it spits out this error message

```
root@7424ff4af3c8:/# wineconsole /var/temp/test_wine/TestWine.exe
wine: created the configuration directory '/root/.wine'
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0014:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0014:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0014:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0 0014:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0 0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 14007 0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x800736b7
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 800736b7
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 800736b7
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0016:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0016:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0018:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0018:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly. Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
0028:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0028:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
002a:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
002a:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly. Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled. wine: configuration in '/root/.wine' has been updated. 
0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

Is there something I'm missing or should I try a different approach entirely?

Comment: Does it work any better if you use `wineconsole --backend=curses …`?

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately. Thanks for the tip though